# Accessing an active element JavaScript ( with or without angular )

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, dom, attributes

## Long story short

I made a tabs module that only requires css in order to work.
There are 2 things I can't figure out

#### 1.Prevent the page from jumping to the links on click while maintaining the hash change that happens to location

Binding to the click event and calling `preventDefault()` via a custom "a" directive on the click  prevents the active state from being applied to the link or section.

#### 2. How to figure out when an element has an active state with javascript. Just javascript. No jQuery or Angular `(":active")` selectors...

jQUery 2.1.1 uses query selector all to do something with `document.activeElement` but I can't figure out... what it does. As far as I can tell there is no such :active property that is accessible with javascript anywhere...

Anyone have any ideas?

#### [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TrZwg1?p=preview)

Note: when you look at the plnkr, if you want the tabs to work you need to *comment OUT* the function call to the tabs directive on line 50 of script.js

## js

```
function tabItem(){
   return ['$location' , '$anchorScroll', function($location, $anchorScroll){
    return{
      restrict: "EA"
      , trandsclude: true
      , scope: {}
      , template: ""
      , link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
          elem.bind('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
          });
      }
    }
  }]
}
tabs.directive('a',tabItem())
```

## html

```
<div class="container" ng-app="tabs">
    <div class="tabs" ng-controller="ThingController as thing">

      <div id="tab1" class="tab">
        <h1 class="tab-header">
            <a href="#tab1" ng-click="thing.dance()" >{{thing.name}} </a>
          </h1>
        <div class="tab-section">
          This is some dummmy content la la la la
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="tab2" class="tab">
        <h1 class="tab-header">
            <a href="#tab2"> {{thing.otherName}} </a>
          </h1>
        <div class="tab-section">
          derp
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="tab3" class="tab">
        <h1 class="tab-header">
            <a href="#tab3"> {{thing.otherName}} </a>
          </h1>
        <div class="tab-section">
          This is some more dummmy content
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

## css

```
 .container{
      display: block;
    }
    .tabs, .container {
      background: #ffffff;
      min-height: 1200px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .tabs, .container, .tab-section, .tab-header a{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .tab{
      display: inline;
    }
    .tab-header {
      background: #eee;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      display: flex;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      width: 145px;
    }

    .tab-header a {
      color: #333;
      display: table-cell;
      font-size: 14px;
      padding: 1.2rem 0;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .tab-section {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -2;
    }
    .tab:not(:active) .tab-section, .tab:target .tab-header {
      background: white;
    }
    .tab:target .tab-section {
      background: #eee;
      top: 60px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var active = document.activeElement;

console.log(active);